# Fastest way to find spesific value over a Numpy array (Nx2 array)

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I use a numpy array as a coordinate system. The coordinates are all of type int. My function checks if both the x and y coordinate is the same as an input coordinate and returns the index of that element in the numpy array.

This is a standalone function in my script, when I run a cProfile script over it, this is the slowest function i got.

My question is, does anyone know a faster way to check this Nx2 numpy array?

This is the function:

```
def findPerson(coordinate, input_array):
    return np.where( (input_array[:,0] == coordinate[0]) & (input_array[:,1] == coordinate[1]) )[0]
```

EDIT:
By request, here is a test sample.

```
predator = np.array([1, 1])

people_array = np.array([[-1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1]])


print(findPerson(predator, people_array))
```

This test script prints out [2], this is the index in people_array that is in the same coordinate as the "predator"

Comment: Could you also supply some sample input and expected output, just to make it easier for us to understand the problem?

Comment: Could there be multiple instances of matches? If not, you can use `np.argmax` in place of `np.where`.

Comment: @Nathan I have edited in an example

Comment: @Divakar This is a random walk simulation with an array. It can be more than one "person" in each coordinate.

Comment: What's the typical dataset size? Also, how do you plan to use these indices?

Comment: The dataset is around 700 rows with a 1x2 array of coordinate. It will be used to check status of the persons(Living or dead) . The indices are used because the status of all persons are stored in another array. ( One array for coordinates and one for the persons personal status)

Comment: My contention was - Can you use the mask, i.e. without the usage of `np.where` there for your later steps. That `np.where` might be a bottleneck in itself.

Comment: The np.where might be the bottleneck, however this is the only place the script uses this function.  My script is a random walk simulations of 700 individuals. With one predator, the script checks if another person is in the same coordinate as the predator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My benchmarking:

```
|---------------------|---------|
|Algorithm            |Time     |
|---------------------|---------|
|Original (findPerson)|  8.4  ms|
|Firman (find_idx)    | 41.8  ms|
|Numba                |  4.89 ms|
|Numba parallel       |  3.21 ms|
|Cython               |  2.70 ms|
|Cython parallel      |  2.90 ms|
|---------------------|---------|
```

My setup:

```
Processor: Intel i5-9600K 3.70GHz, 6 core
Versions:
Python:  3.8.0
Numba:  0.46.0
Cython: 0.29.14
Numpy:  1.17.4
```

My data setup (the original array is too small, so I decided to copy it 1 mln times):

```
predator = np.array([1, 1])
people_array = np.array([[-1, 1], [2, 2], [1, 1]]*1000000)
```

So the fastest option is to use Cython (code as it works in Jupyter):

```
%%cython -a

import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from numpy cimport ndarray
from cython.parallel import prange
from libc.stdint cimport uint32_t, int64_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.infer_types(True)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)

def cy_loop(int64_t[:] coordinate,int64_t[:,:] input_array):

    alen = input_array.shape[0]
    cdef uint32_t[:] res1 = np.empty(alen,np.uint32)
    cdef uint32_t ii = 0
    for i in range(alen):
        if (input_array[i,0] == coordinate[0]) and (input_array[i,1] == coordinate[1]):
            res1[ii] = i
            ii = ii + 1
    return np.asarray(res1[:ii])
```

The easiest to setup is Numba non-parallel:

```
@numba.njit(nogil=True)
def findPerson_nb2(coordinate, input_array):
    return np.where( (input_array[:,0] == coordinate[0]) & (input_array[:,1] == coordinate[1]) )[0]
```

Numba parallel (maybe it is also easy to setup, but parallel programs could be tricky):

```
import math
@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def findPerson_nb4(coordinate, input_array, alen):
#     alen = input_array.shape[0]
    n_batches = 768   #6*16*8
    batch_size = math.ceil(alen/n_batches)
    res = np.empty((n_batches, batch_size),dtype=np.int64)
    res_len = np.empty(n_batches,dtype=np.int64)
    for i in numba.prange(n_batches):
        start = i*batch_size
        if i == (n_batches - 1):
            end = alen
        else:
            end = (i+1)*batch_size
        res_i = start + np.where( (input_array[start:end,0] == coordinate[0]) & (input_array[start:end,1] == coordinate[1]))[0]
        ailen = res_i.shape[0]
        res[i,:ailen] = res_i
        res_len[i] = ailen
    return res, res_len

@numba.njit()
def myconcat(a_in, a_in_len, alen):
    res = np.empty(alen,dtype=np.int64)
    ii = 0
    for i in range(res_len.shape[0]):
        for j in range(res_len[i]):
            res[ii] = a_in[i,j]
            ii = ii + 1
    return res, ii
```

Cython parallel:

```
%%cython -a --compile-args=/openmp --link-args=/openmp --force

import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from numpy cimport ndarray
from cython.parallel import prange
from libc.stdint cimport uint32_t, int64_t
from libc.math cimport ceil

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.infer_types(True)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)

def cy_loop3(int64_t[:] coordinate,int64_t[:,:] input_array):

    alen = input_array.shape[0]
    cdef uint32_t n_batches = 6*16   #6*16*8
    cdef uint32_t batch_size = <uint32_t>ceil(alen/n_batches)
    cdef uint32_t[:,:] res = np.empty((n_batches, batch_size),dtype=np.uint32)
    cdef uint32_t[:] res_len = np.empty(n_batches,dtype=np.uint32)
    cdef uint32_t start, end, ii, i, j
    for i in prange(n_batches, nogil=True):
        start = i*batch_size
        if i == (n_batches - 1):
            end = alen
        else:
            end = (i+1)*batch_size

        ii = 0
        for j in range(start,end):
            if (input_array[j,0] == coordinate[0]) and (input_array[j,1] == coordinate[1]):
                res[i, ii] = j
                ii = ii + 1
        res_len[i] = ii
    return np.asarray(res), np.asarray(res_len)
```

My tests:

```
%%timeit
findPerson(predator, people_array)

%%timeit
find_idx(predator, people_array)

%%timeit
findPerson_nb2(predator, people_array)

%%timeit
alen = people_array.shape[0]
res, res_len = findPerson_nb4(predator, people_array,alen)
ar, alen1 = myconcat(res,res_len, alen)
res = ar[:alen1]

%%timeit
cy_loop(predator, people_array)

%%timeit
cy_loop3(predator, people_array)
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight in both Cypty and numba. Your examples were to great help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
import numpy as np
def find_idx(pt, ptslist):
    return np.where(np.all(pt == ptslist, axis=1))[0]
```

It also works for more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunable it were slower than my function.